org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec
I trying to automate Ixigo mobile android app through real device "XIAOMI 11 LITE NE" , but when am executing the testcase am getting the error as WebDriverException.
Here is my @test case
 
@BeforeSuite
     public void StartServer() throws MalformedURLException {
        service = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\anile\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js")).withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723).build();
        service.start();
        System.out.println("*******Sever has been started!!********");
        
        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        options.setCapability("deviceName", "XIAOMI 11 Lite NE");
        options.setCapability("app", "C:\\Dragonflytest\\Appium\\Resourceses\\ixigo.apk");
        options.setCapability("udid", "3c840470");
        options.setCapability("platformName", "android");
        options.setCapability("platformVersion", "14");
        options.setCapability("appWaitForLaunch", false);
        //options.setCapability("noReset", true);
        
         driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"),options);

        
    }

@Test
    public void Test1() throws InterruptedException {
        //System.out.println("success");
        Activity activity = new Activity("com.ixigo", "com.ixigo.home.HomeActivity");
        
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("mobile:startActivity",ImmutableMap.of("intent","com.ixigo/com.ixigo.home.HomeActivity"));
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement oneway = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"Round Trip\")"));
        if (oneway.isDisplayed()==true) {
            System.out.println("Element is displayed and visibled:"+oneway.getText());
        }else if (oneway.isDisplayed()==false) {
            System.out.println("Element is not displayed and visibled:"+oneway.getText());
        }
    
        wait.waitForElementToClick(oneway, 2);
        
    Thread.sleep(5000);

